# Notice: Undefined index: font-weight

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theme

tengo un problema y es que en mi pagina web de WordPress me aparece una noticia. No se bien como solucionarlo, ya me contacte con el host y no pudieron ayudarme. a contuniacion adjunto la noticia.

> Notice: Undefined index: font-weight in
> /home/argendat/public_html/wp-content/themes/colormag-pro/inc/enqueue-scripts.php
> on line 285

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes compartir la linea 285 del archivo enqueue-scripts.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

el problema que estás teniendo es que alguna configuración del theme esta vacía y los creadores del theme no están manejando correctamente ese valor vacío. Es un problema del THEME, no de Wordpress ni del host. Deberías contactarte con el soporte del THEME.

Si no te dan soporte, vos por tu lado podés probar:

1. Revisar que toda las configuraciones estén cargadas y guardar todos las instancias de configuración.
2. Desinstalar e instalar y el theme.
3. Podrías crear un child-theme y mejorar el manejo de la excepción con un condicional del tipo:

```php
if(isset($array['font-weight'])){
//introducir el código aquí

} else { 
//introducir el código aquí para manejar la excepción.
}
```

4. Decirle a Wordpress que no te muestre errores no graves ("Notices" no es un error grave) configurando en el archivo wp-config.php en el root de tu sitio la variable WP_DEBUG a falso: https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG , pero dejarias de ver en pantalla este tipo de errors no controlados, que en algún momento se puede convertir en un Warning o Fatal Error.

Comment: esto no tiene nada que ver con como resolver el notice. cuando el problema puede ser que falte un if o algo no se este controlando...

Comment: Es cierto, pero la respuesta buscó orientar al usuario sobre:

a) Quien era el responsable del problema
b) Asociado a que está

Es cierto que podría explorar la linea y fixear la función haciendo un child-theme. Voy a agregar eso en la respuesta. Gracias.

Comment: seria conveniente :D